# How run a massive test on html page that have a analytic code?

Tags: matomo, taurus, piwiktracker

I have Piwik/Matomo running and connected with my html page. I am using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org) to test with several requests my html page.

The propose of this is colect the page views on Piwik/Matomo, but this only do the requests, not run the JavaScript analytic code.

Have a way to do that? A especial configuration? Or another software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- use Webdriver to use browsers that will call it but it will scale less per machine in terms of VUs. Have a look at :

  - https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/
- another option is to use analytics API to manually call the tracking api using ids extracted from webpage and passing them